# Can someone explain how this diode works?

Tags: diodes, schematics

[image: Motorola Engineering Note 100, Page 4]

I found this schematic in the Motorola Engineering Note 100, page 4.

I'm not able to understand how the diode from -12 volts going onto the serial output line works. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Missing link to spec

Comment: Mark, I just took a look at the Note you mentioned. There's two details of interest that I learned. One is that the "serial" I/O is a 4-20 mA TTY interface designed to operate (or co-operate) with an [ASR-33 device](https://va3ngc.weebly.com/asr-33-documentation.html), which used the old pre-RS232 method at the time for serial communications. So it supplies a \$24\:\text{V}\$ total potential.

Comment: @Jonk the digital current loop of ASR33 and friends is not the same as 4-20 mA current loop for industrial instrumentation.

Comment: Looks like an ancient design for a 1200 baud current loop

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The MIKBUG dates to 1975, or so. They almost certainly intended to work with the ASR-33, I thought. It was a quite common device. Are you saying differently? You may be right.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Ah! [Look here](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/downloads/14064). Yup. ASR-33 specifically mentioned.

Comment: @jonk. No, I'm not saying the device was not meant to interoperate with ASR-33. I'm saying that ASR-33 used digital current loop, which is not the same as 4-20 mA current loop (which is analog.)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Oh. Sorry. You are right about that. It was a simple 20 mA interface. (Which is obvious from the schematic.) I should not have written that 4 mA in there. It just flowed out without thinking about it. Good catch.

Comment: @MarkJacobs It's now obvious why the diode is there. Can you see why? (It will take some additional knowledge about the old ASR-33 interface and the lack of standards with 20 mA current loop that developed afterwards.) And if anyone actually has a working ASR-33 that needs a home, definitely **I** will find a home for it!

Comment: @jonk Yes, now I understand why the diode is there. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @MarkJacobs Cool!! This [clue page](http://www.kavina-systems.com/articals/current_loop_app_note.html) was going to be my next offering to help. There is no necessary knowledge, a priori, about who is the *generator*!

Answer (score 8):

I suspect the reason for the diode is that the 20mA current loop is driving a solenoid in the ASR33, so the diode forms a catch diode.

It is not returned to ground because speed is very important in this application, and -12 allows the magnetic field to collapse faster.

Comment: Receiving seems to indeed happen with a [solenoid](https://www.revk.uk/2020/12/connecting-asr33-teletype-to-esp32.html?m=1)

Comment: @Unimportant Yeah. But this wasn't exactly the answer I was looking to see. Keep in mind that by the time the MIKBUG was released current loop was in fairly wide use (the ASR-33 was 12 years earlier and before that the military had been using current loop as well) in a variety of devices using anything from 20 to 60 mA as their current loop and -- perhaps more significantly here -- a *receiver* might itself have a current generator and expect the transmitter to operate a kind of on/off switch. Hmm. I wonder how that might possibly work here? ;)

Comment: @jonk So the receiver sends out current trough "serial common" which returns trough the diode to the "serial output". When the opto switches on *it* will be supplying the current to the "serial output" rather then the current coming in trough "serial common" and the receiver detects this?

Comment: @Unimportant Not quite. When the darlington is actively pulling up, the diode in question is ***forced*** into a reverse-bias state. It ***must*** block current. But when the darlington is relaxed (not actively pulling that diode's cathode up and forcing it into reverse-bias) then the diode is completely free-wheeling and can pass current. But yes! Close! It's a beautiful system! First time I encountered this, but putting the pieces together was fun!

Comment: @jonk total available voltage is 24V minus a couple diode drops so say 22.5V. Voltage drop across the 820 ohm R is 16V ish at 20mA so that leaves 6V or so across the input.

Comment: Maybe overthinking this- the ASR33 and later machines did not drive the solenoid directly, but there might be some inductance in the wiring and the 4N33 is a bit fragile so the blocking and fly back diodes. Worth a couple 1 cent diodes.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I may write something. But I'm going to take a day first.

Comment: @jonk oooh anticipation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Hmm. Maybe I'll take two and it will be even better! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the purpose of the diode from various replies to my original post. First of all, it is important to know that the diode in question is only involved in the control of the 20 mA current loop, not RS-232 (The RS-232c line is meant for that). It's purpose is to allow -12 volts onto the serial output line when the optocoupler *4N33* isn't putting 12 volts on and when the voltage on the receiving end is lower than -12 volts (Which may provided by that serial common line). The resistor's purpose is to limit the current. Eventually the serial output and serial common lines may go to a machine that will measure the current going from one line to the other and use that information to transmit some serial data!

Answer (score 1):

It is a voltage spike protector. THe 1n4007 on the transistor keeps it from seeing Positive spikes from the load ( coil or long wound wires or lightning) and the diode  to -12 keeps the input from ever going above -12v so the optitransistor never sees more than -12 on its emitter junction when its turned off which tends to have a lower vbe limit.